# How to count the characters within quotes?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, grep, sed

Example:

```
Known Data: Total population = "150"
```

Question: Using bash how can I find out the number of characters within quotes? and assign that output to a variable?

Comment: Just one occurrence of "string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in `bash` and assuming there is a single occurrence of `"string"`, you could do:

```
str='Known Data: Total population = "150"'
strip=${str/\"*\"/}
len=$(( ${#str} - ${#strip} -2 ))
```

then:

```
echo $len
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Using grep:

```
var=$(grep -Po '(?<=").*(?=")' fileName | tr -d '\n' | wc -c)
```

for your example returns:

```
echo $var
3
```

---

Using sed:

```
var=$(sed -r 's/^.*"(.*)".*/\1/' fileName | tr -d '\n' | wc -c)
```

Comment: If i were to simply Echo the statement first, is it possible to count the characters and output the value? the reason why i ask this is , there might be many instances of quoted text in a file, i have to identify a particular pattern, in this case 'Total population = ' and then find the next immediate quoted text and count the number of characters in it.

Comment: @SaiVarun Yes. You can `echo` the line too: `var=$( echo 'line bla bal "494" foo bar' | grep ... )`.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
string='Known Data: Total population = "150"'
var=$(awk -F\" '{print length($2)}' <<< "$string")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `perl`**:

One/first match per line:

```
perl -ne '{ print; m/"(.*?)"/; print length($1),"\n"; }'
```

Multiple matches per line:

```
perl -ne '{ print; while (m/"(.*?)"/g) { print length($1),"\n"; } }'
```

---

Your example:

```
echo 'Known Data: Total population = "150"' | \
    perl -ne '{ print; m/"(.*?)"/; print length($1),"\n"; }'

Known Data: Total population = "150"
3
```

Example with 2 quoted strings:

```
echo 'Known Data: Total population = "150"
Two quoted strings: "70" and "6000"' | \
perl -ne '{ print; while (m/"(.*?)"/g) { print length($1),"\n"; } }'

Known Data: Total population = "150"
3
Two quoted strings: "70" and "6000"
2
4
```

Leave out the `print;` if you don't need the original line printed.

e.g.:

```
var=$(echo 'Known Data: Total population = "150"' | \
        perl -ne '{ m/"(.*?)"/; print length($1),"\n"; }')
echo $var
3
```